How to flash Altera EPM7256E?
I am working on legacy bit of hardware. I see that EPM7256S can be flashed as usual, via JTAG using standard (modern) tools, so this is quite clear.
But how to flash EPM7256E? Are the any inexpensive 3rd party programmers which can flash it in 2024 or information on programming protocol? Is it only parallel high-voltage?

Your choices are severely limited.
Indeed, the 'E' flavor does not have a JTAG interface.  The most direct route is to use a modern day (loosely defined here) 3rd party programmer.  It is not in-system programable via ByteBlaster.
The one solution that I could find uses a $1000 programmer:
https://www.xeltek.com/manual-programmers/universal-programmers/supepro6100n/
...with a ~$450 chip adapter/carrier (depending on pin count):
https://www.xeltek.com/devices-supported/altera-device-programmers/
You didn't define your version of inexpensive - however to me this is not that. ¯\(ツ)/¯
Good Luck!
